# Как динамически включить Draggable для выбранной метки из objectManager?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, объекты

```
objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(objectId, {
        preset: 'islands#greenAutoIcon',
        draggable: true
    });
```

так не работает.

Собственно нужно сделать, чтобы метка стала перемещаемой после нажатия в DOM кнопки типа "редактирование":

```
$('#point_edit').click(function(e){

    var object = objectManager.objects.balloon.getData();
    var objectId = object.id;

    objectManager.setFilter( function(obj) {    
         return obj.id == objectId;
    });

    objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(objectId, {
             preset: 'islands#greenAutoIcon',
         draggable: true
    }); 

});
```

Как итог: иконка меняется, остальные метки скрыты, а перетаскивание не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден в документации:

> ObjectManager:
>
> Обратите внимание, что у объектов, отрисованных на карте через данный менеджер, нельзя включать режимы редактирования и перетаскивания.

Придется для обычного изменения properties метки (для редактирования метки) из Менеджера объектов, удалять(скрывать) ее и создавать новый Plasemark, и сохранив его данные, заменять существующую метку....